# Adding Batch values with an array

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I've trying to insert batch data from array in to Sqlite3 for my mobile project.

my code seems to be works fine, but it doesn't insert all data.

**PS: I edited my code:**

```
        -(BOOL) saveBatchData:(NSArray *)userSourceID userDestID:(NSArray *)userDestID message:(NSArray *)message sentDate:(NSArray *)sentDate
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<[message count]; i++)
        {

            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into messages (userSourceID,userDestID, message, sentDate) values (\"%d\",\"%d\", \"%@\",\"%@\")",[[userSourceID objectAtIndex:i] integerValue],[[userDestID objectAtIndex:i] intValue], [message objectAtIndex:i],[sentDate objectAtIndex:i]];

            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);

            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);

                return YES;

            } else {

                NSLog(@"Hata = %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));

                return NO;
            }

            sqlite3_reset(statement);

        }

        sqlite3_close(database);

    }

    return NO;
}
```

The output  seems to be , function just added few rows on 39 elements of array ( i think it's 4 ) . Can someone help me what's  my mistake over here  ?

Regards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are preparing lots of statements, but execute only the last one.

Move the call to `sqlite3_step` into the loop.

Please note that you must call `sqlite3_finalize` for every statement you have prepared, regardless of whether the step suceeded or not.

You must not jump out of the function without calling `sqlite3_close`.

You must not call `sqlite3_reset` after the statement has been finalized.

Comment: And one more question, sqlite3_reset is also  in function scope.. You mean moving it in for loop ?

Comment: Now you're calling `sqlite3_finalize` twice, and you're jumping out of the loop the first time.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see sqlite3_finalize in the for loop . Now I edited my code.

Comment: I tried my code current  edited version, but still does not add all sql statements ..

Comment: Because you still execute `return` after the first step.

Comment: :(( , http://prntscr.com/1nw1t9, I start to get that message after i removed return in the is scope . Think problem is in sqlite3_reset function...

Comment: You must never call `sqlite3_reset` after `sqlite3_finalize`. In you program, you do not need `sqlite3_reset` at all.