# Not able to parse large json response

Tags: ios, json, swift, sqlite, parsing

I have a certain json response which has a size of over 5 MB. I'm parsing it like so..

```
do {
     let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root
      .self, from: dataOfAllOrganizations!)

      let organizationLists = Organization()

       for element in result.organizations {
            organizationLists.address = element.address
            organizationLists.Name = element.Name
            ....

             // Inserting into SQLite database
       let isInserted = sharedInstance.saveOrganization_Lists(organizationLists)

        }                                 
       } catch {
         print(error)
      }
```

But using this parsing technique, it's taking a very huge and unusually long amount of time to parse all data. I also tried to parse data from the json file itself(by dragging the json file to the project). But even that's not working. Is there an alternate approach to quicky parse such huge data and dump them into the database.

**EDIT 1** This is how the root class looks like..

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let organizations : [Organization1]
}

struct Organization1 : Decodable {
    let address: String
    let Name: String
    ...
}
```

And this is the json...

```
{
    "organizations": [
        {
            "Addrss": "myAddress",
            "Name": "TheName",
            .....   
        },

       ..(There are hundreds of more such objects.)..
    ]
}
```

**EDIT 2** This is the code for `saveOrganization_Lists`

```
func saveOrganization_Lists(_ items: Organization) -> Bool {
       var isInserted = false
       sharedInstance.database!.open()

       isInserted = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Organization (address,Name,...) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,)",withArgumentsIn: [items.name ?? "",items.address ?? "",...])

       sharedInstance.database!.close()
       return isInserted

   }
```

Comment: I know the JSON is quite long but it will be quite tough for anyone to help without seeing the actual JSON along with your Root class. Another suggestion, you can use [Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/) and it can generate a Codable class for you to decode your JSON.

Comment: Have edited the question with the changes @AlanS.

Comment: What is taking a long time here, the decoding or the db insert or both? Have you measured them separately?

Comment: since I have used a for-loop maybe it's taking a lot of time to loop through each of the thousands of elements and then inserting them to the db. It's the looping tha's time consuming it seems...

Comment: "Maybe" and "it seems" wasn't exactly the information I was after, you need to update and clarify your question so we know what the issue is and possibly can help you.

Comment: The moment the code hits the line `let isInserted = sharedInstance.saveOrganization_Lists(organizationLists)`, the particular entry is added to the database. So it's the looping through the thousands of records that's taking the time.

Comment: Then update your question to clarify this.

Comment: Wait. Are you inserting them one by one? Can't you insert them by batch (which should be much faster)? Is `organizationLists` just a temp var that you insert? What is the code of `saveOrganization_Lists`? How do you write into your Database exactly?

Comment: I have edited the question and included the code for `saveOrganization_Lists ` @Larme. Also, I haven't yet tried inserting in batch...Would you maybe mind suggesting how its done..?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468827/adding-batch-values-with-an-array/18469121#18469121 I'm not familiar with SQL, but... Using it, quick suggestions: https://pastebin.com/wT0JzqfL

Comment: And if batch insert doesn't work you can at least change the code so that you do not open and close the db connection for each insert.